# Driving high-powered LED with demanding requirements

Tags: led

I have just purchased this impressive looking 100W "7-band" LED multichip, apparently it's the latest innovation. My problem is the chip's voltage demands are far lower than what ordinary 100W drivers operate at; this chip requires 22-26V/3.5A, while 100W drivers almost exclusively run at 30-36V/3.0A.

I asked the creator and he said it would not work and would most probably blink constantly. So since constant current drivers look out of the question, would it be possible to use a power supply with some kind of buck regulator with an adjustable voltage/current potentiometer such as [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-DC-Power-Supply-Boost-Converter-Step-up-Module-10-60V-to-12-80V-600W-/111035774503?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item19da3f7627)?

I also have a digital ammeter/voltmeter display which could be connected between the two would make potentiometer adjustments accurate, and I have a friend who can wire all the above up for me.

Comment: Blink? What sort of internal circuitry does it have that it would blink if not supplied enough current?

Comment: im not sure, but he stated a driver running at 30-36v@3.0A would make the chip blink continuously. the voltage is lower at 22-26v, and its a pain to find driver. i have noticed these buck dc/dc adjustable regulator say "led driver", but at what capacity do they work to power such high wattage led's?.

Comment: Please consider improving your question by using the rules of written English, like capitalizing the word "I" and putting a question mark at the end of your question.

Comment: Where is the datasheet for this LED? I wouldn't buy LED-assemblies on eBay without the matching power supply and without any datasheet.

Comment: @Ignatio, if the supply sees undervoltage at rated current it may trigger short circuit protection, and get into a shutdown, restart cycle.

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes sense.